# c++ fork() & execl() dont wait, detach completely

Tags: c++, unix, fork

So I have a simple fork and exec program. It works pretty good but I want to be able to detach the process that is started, I try a fork with no wait:

```
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    perror("Error with Fork()");
else if(pid > 0) {
    return "";
}
else {
    if(execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", cmddo, (char*) 0) < 0) perror("execl()");
    exit(0);
}
```

It starts the proc fine but when my main app is closed - so is my forked proc.

How do I keep the forked process running after the main proc (that started it) closes?

Thanks :D

Comment: This doesn't really have much to with C++ but way more with UNIX! Probably all you really want is to ignore `SIGHUP` in your `fork()`ed process as this is normally the one which bring the program down effectively.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: SIGHUP it is. Put it as an answer!

Comment: I did try sighup in the command, sighup <command> &

Comment: well, you would want to try `nohup <command>`.

Comment: thanks i did try that and no avail - found more articles on google indicating forking again and running sighup, looking @ http://www.microhowto.info/howto/cause_a_process_to_become_a_daemon_in_c.html#id2407077 atm

Comment: Note: use `_Exit` instead of `exit` in case `execl` fails. Otherwise you will be closing all FILE handles of the parent process (as well as other resources).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Various things to do if you want to start a detached/daemon process:

- fork again and exit the first child (so the second child process no longer has the original process as its parent pid)
- call setsid(2) to get a new session and process group
- reopen stdin/stdout/stderr to dereference the controlling tty, if there was one. Or, for example, you might have inherited a pipe stdout that will be broken and give you SIGPIPE if you try to write it.
- chdir to / to get away from the ancestor's current directory

Comment: this worked for me, had to fork again and setsid, then with &>/dev/null on the end of my command it started as intended - not ignoring &  - what you said is talked about on the link I found earlier, answer is within both - thanks! http://www.microhowto.info/howto/cause_a_process_to_become_a_daemon_in_c.html#id2407077

Comment: since the forked proc has an identical process it seems to duplicate my 'ServerSocket' that the parent process has (as its a damon) - so when killed - the forked process is still running, hanging the socket, maybe worth a new topic here at stack.

Comment: yes, I know some server programs that actually go through all FDs 0 to 255, closing them just in case. You can mark FDs in your parent/server process as F_CLOEXEC so they won't be inherited across the exec call, use fcntl.

Answer (score 4):

Probably all you really want is to ignore SIGHUP in your fork()ed process as this is normally the one which brings the program down. That is, what you need to do is

```
signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
```

Using `nohup` arranges for a reader to be present which would avoid possibly writing to close pipe. To avoid this you could either arrange for standard outputs not to be available or to also ignore `SIGPIPE`. There are a number of signals which terminate your program when not ignore (see `man signal`; some signals can't be ignored) but the one which will be sent to the child is is `SIGHUP`.

Comment: does this assume the forked proc is something i wrote? understanding that signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN); goes in the forked app so it ignores the signal to close

Comment: two things: 1. you should ignore the signal before `fork()`ing. If necessary restore the original in the parent. Otherwise, you run the risk that the child receives the signal before it had the chance to replace it. 2. effectively, you want to `fork()` again and wait for the child: this way it doesn't matter if the ultimately started program ignores the signal or not and there is also no race condition.

Answer (score 0):

EX1: When client not exit, no wait

```
#include <spawn.h>
extern char** environ; //posix_spawn using environ that declare in glibc-2.xx/posix/environ.c
void main()
{
    pid_t   spawnid;
    char    param[64] = {0};
    char*   args[] = {"/usr/drive_server", param, NULL};
    posix_spawn(&spawnid, "/usr/drive_server", NULL, NULL, args, 
    environ);
    getchar();
}
```

EX2: When client exit, wait subprocess detach

```
#include <spawn.h>
extern char** environ;
void main()
{
    pid_t   spawnid;
    char    param[64] = {0};
    pid_t   sessionid;
    char*   args[] = {"/usr/drive_server", param, NULL};
    
    posix_spawn(&spawnid, "/usr/drive_server", NULL, NULL, args, environ);
    
    sessionid = 0;
    while( sessionid != spawnid )
    {
        sessionid = getsid(spawnid);
        printf("sessionid id %d\n", sessionid);
        usleep(200000);
    }
}

    //subprocess file
    void main()
    {
        setsid(); //detach
        getchar();
    }
```

EX3: when system have setsid command, no wait

```
#include <spawn.h>
extern char** environ;
void main()
{
    pid_t   id_spawn;
    char*   args[] = {"/usr/bin/setsid", "/volume1/drive_server", serviceName8, NULL};

    posix_spawn(&id_spawn, "/usr/bin/setsid", NULL, NULL, args, environ);
    printf("drive_server* spawn id %d\n", id_spawn);
}
```

there are 2 sources code can be referred to

1. util-linux-2.xx.x/sys-utils/setsid.c
2. busybox-1.xx.x/util-linux/setsid.c