# c++ ServerSocket(), FD_CLOEXEC, fork() & execl()

Tags: c++

I had issues trying to background a command in my app, so I was [told here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888563/c-fork-execl-dont-wait-detach-completely) to double fork and clear some of the settings, so this was my result:

```
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    perror("Error with Fork()");
else if(pid > 0) {
    return "";
}
if (setsid()==-1) {
    Log("failed to become a session leader");
}

if (chdir("/") == -1) {
    Log("failed to change working directory");
}

umask(0);
close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
if (open("/dev/null",O_RDONLY) == -1) {
    Log("failed to reopen stdin");
}
if (open("/dev/null",O_WRONLY) == -1) {
    Log("failed to reopen stdout");
}
if (open("/dev/null",O_RDWR) == -1) {
    Log("failed to reopen stderr");
}

signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
Log("No return, forking..");
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    perror("Error with Fork()");
else if(pid > 0) {
    return "";
} else {        
    if(execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", cmddo, (char*) 0) < 0) perror("execl()");
    exit(0);
}
```

Double forking fixed the issue of the execl'd proc stopping when its parent is closed but it left me with the execl'd process holding onto the parents socket, so when the parent tries to start again it can't.

Here is my parent socket stuff:

```
ServerSocket server(listenport);
while(true)
{   
    ServerSocket* new_sock = new ServerSocket();

    server.accept (*new_sock);

    pthread_t thread;
    int rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &LoadThread, (void*)(new_sock));

    if (rc) Log_warn("Fatal Error: pthread_create() #%d", rc);
    pthread_detach(thread);
}
```

I was told to FD_CLOEXEC on the socket in my last question but I do not understand how-to do that - and google (plus stack) isn't showing me much help in regards to that.

How do I FD_CLOEXEC on my ServerSocket() so when I fork/execl a sub process it won't hang my socket?

Thanks :D

**ANSWER**:
As told below to clear the fd's out - my code actually had this, and it worked for me:

```
struct rlimit       rl;
int                 i;

if (rl.rlim_max == RLIM_INFINITY)
  rl.rlim_max = 1024;

for (i = 0; (unsigned) i < rl.rlim_max; i++)
  close(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FD_CLOEXEC` is a flag that can be set on the file descriptor -- its effect is that when a process holding the handle calls `exec()`, the descriptor is closed.

Use

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, (long)FD_CLOEXEC);
```

to set the flag; for this to work, you need to access the actual file descriptor.

Also, `setsid()` is fully sufficient to disassociate yourself from the parent process group, and while double `fork()` also works, it does not earn you brownie points with the embedded folks.

And last, there is no guarantee that after closing the first three filedescriptors, the next fds opened will be those three; it is better to use

```
fd newstdin = open(...);
if(dup2(newstdin, STDIN_FILENO) != 0) { /* handle error */ }
close(newstdin);
```

Comment: i think I do understand the 2nd and 3rd points but my first, and main one, I am still confused to - does the ServerSocket() make a fd? The only fd's in my app are when its set to be a daemon, those I already FD_CLOEXEC. fd0 = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
 fcntl (fd0, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);  thanks!

Comment: The ServerSocket has an fd internally, yes. This is an implementation detail and should in principle not concern your application, but usually there is a way to break the abstraction (alternatively, try to find out whether the ServerSocket can be taught to set the close-on-exec flag, which would be the right thing to do).

Comment: Note that you are not supposed to close the standard file descriptors on `exec()` -- these are to be inherited by the child, and otherwise it wouldn't make sense to set them up in the first place.

Comment: The principle is fairly simple: your program is `execve()`'d with those three file descriptors open, and other programs expect the same, so these three should not be close-on-exec. You may pass other file descriptors if the other program expects it (gnupg for example has a `--status-fd` parameter that tells it to write machine-readable status to a certain fd), other than that, it is generally a good idea to close the fds.

Comment: Speaking of which -- this can be achieved a lot simpler: just go through all possible fd numbers and call `close()` right before the `exec*()` call. That should also catch your server socket.

Comment: ok thanks again :D still above my head, ill have to do more digging.

Comment: After the `fork()`, you check whether you're in the parent or the child process. In the child, `close()` all file descriptors you do not want to pass through `execve()` (which ultimately all the *exec** functions invoke).

Comment: thanks a lot Simon! I had to post a job for this to get a freelancer to help more as its above my limited c++ skills, I accepted your answer as it is sufficient - its just my skills that are not.